# javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException while querying AuditEntity when record exists in database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, exception, hibernate-envers

I am currently using Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE, Hibernate Envers 5.3.7.Final.

When I query for my AuditEntity for my User class, it will throw the javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException saying my User record does not exist. However, in database it does exist. Anyone have any idea why?

User Entity

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Audited
@Table(name = "[user]") 
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    @Length(max = 20)
    @Unique
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;


    @Audited(targetAuditMode = NOT_AUDITED)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CreatedBy
    private User createByUser;

    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createDatetime;

    @Audited(targetAuditMode = NOT_AUDITED)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @LastModifiedBy
    private User updateByUser;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime updateDatetime;

    @Column
    private Boolean active = true;

    @Column
    private Boolean deleted = false;

}
```

While querying for the audit entity, the property createByUser updateByUser throws the exception javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find data.entity.User with id 2. However, in the database I have this record.

```
AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
AuditQuery query = auditReader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(User.class, true, true);
query.add(AuditEntity.id().eq(id));

return query.getResultList();
```

**EDITED on 2018-12-05**

The problem seems to be the problem with this id 2 record, I insert this records from backend and not via the frontend which will generate a record in _aud table. Not sure how does this auditing logic works.

Comment: Can you see if the query being executed is to locate the entity in the main ORM tables or is the query looking into the audit tables?  It should be the former.  Either way, it sounds like its a bug.

Comment: If this audit query is ran for records which i created programmatically, it works fine. this problem only occurs when i create the record via backend database inserts. strange..

Comment: Can you extract the records from id = 2 from user and audit? Also from an user that works. Did you added a revision_id for the record/ records inserted manually in backend ?

Comment: As @CosminConstantinescu points out, what are the differences between the records created by Envers and your manual insertion?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that it is indeed due to missing records in the _aud table.

Instead of inserting test records directly to backend. I decided to create a routine in the Application class of the spring boot.

```
@SpringBootApplication(
        exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {WebApplication.class})
@EnableAsync
@EnableCaching
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class WebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner setUpInitialData(
            EntityRepository1 entityRepository1,
            EntityRepository2 entityRepository2) {

        return args -> {
        // do all data insertion here...
        };
    }
}
```

Either this or the _aud table must also contains the corresponding entry for the entity.